# Salesforce android SDK ...forcedroid is not recognized

Tags: salesforce

I am new to the salesforce android sdk.I am trying to create a hybrid app , i have installed forcedroid package ,jdk 1.7 ,ant1.9.3,node.js,salesforce mobile sdk but I'm getting error like "forcedroid is not recognised as a internal or external comand,operable program or batch file" in the command prompt .Please help me

Comment: What documentation you refer? How did you installed forcedroid package? Have you installed it using npm command?

Answer (score 1):

forcedroid is not added in your path. Usually if you install using npm, it will be added automatically. Please add it to path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you install `forcedroid` via `npm` it is set on the `path` variables of your system; Windows in my example. But for me it didn't!

Here is what I fixed it:

**Tldr;** By adding it manually to path variables.

Typically forcedroid or any repo is installed inside the `npm` directory wherever it is located.
default location for `Windows` is:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\forcedroid
```

Here `forcedroid` is the file name.

So go to your Environment Variables and under 'Path' (where you typically setup all your cmd paths), You add a new one

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

NOTICE: the path only till the `\npm` directory. Should now work!